# Create archive file with original the file structure, so that un-archive will extract those files/folder to exactly where it was

Tags: linux, zip

Let's say I have a file structure like so:

```
/
 file0.txt
 file00.txt
 --folderA
    fileA1.txt
    fileA2.txt
 --folderB
    fileB.dat
    fileB.txt
    noisefile.noise123
   --folderBB
      fileBB1.dat
      fileBB2.dat
      fileBB.txt
      noisefile.noise6hy
```

and creating a zip file (from `/`) using this command:

```
zip -r archive.zip /*.txt /folderA/*.txt /folderB -x /folderB/noisefile.\*
```

This command doesn't maintain the original file structure, that when I unzip it, it will not be unzipped into the place where it once was. Is there a way to achieve this, with or without(other available tools) using the `zip`?

Similar analogy would be a `.deb` file where `data.tar.gz` contains all the structure, and when installing it extract to the original place. The reason that I'm not using `deb` file is because it will be installed(registered?) on the system, where what I wanted to do was just to backup and restore files. Maybe `deb` could do what I want but I didn't know?

Comment: Zip files don't allow absolute paths. See https://superuser.com/a/1415571/865163

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Actually you did answered my question (I mentioned the tool doesn't have to be exclusively `zip`. That seems to be what I'm looking for, thank you! Will change the title from `zip` to `archive`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### General way

Every archiver that stores relative paths and extracts files in the current working directory can be "forced" to do what you want. You need to

- create an archive from the root directory (`/`) as you do in the question (providing absolute paths may be enough, even if you're in another directory);
- extract the archive from the root directory.

So `cd /` (or `pushd /`) is crucial.

In particular this applies to `zip`. I read your question as a request to simplify the process, to get rid of `cd /`. The ability to interpret the target file (`archive.zip` in the question) relatively to the true working directory would also be nice; obviously after `cd /` `archive.zip` means `/archive.zip`.

---

#### With `tar`

The desired functionality is available in `tar`. In Linux, `tar` is a common archiver, although not required by POSIX (POSIX archiver is [`pax`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html)).

With `tar`, its `--absolute-names`/`-P` option is useful in your case. [The manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_22.html#g_t_002d_002dabsolute_002dnames) states:

> ```
> --absolute-names
> -P
> ```
>
> Normally when creating an archive, `tar` strips an initial `/` from member names, and when extracting from an archive `tar` treats names specially if they have initial `/` or internal `..`. This option disables that behavior. See section [Absolute File Names](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_54.html#SEC120).

There are few conditions to achieve what you want:

- When creating an archive, you need to provide absolute paths to files to be archived. In your example `/*.txt /folderA/*.txt /folderB` expand to absolute paths. Note it's the shell who expands unquoted `*`; then `tar` (or `zip` in the example) receives expanded paths.
- When creating an archive, you need to use `-P` (or `--absolute-names`). If you don't then `tar` will store each path without the leading `/` (you will still be able to extract files while in `/`, this is exactly the general way introduced above).
- When extracting, you need to use `-P` again. If you don't then `tar` will remove the leading `/` from each path anyway and you will recreate the stored directory tree as a subtree of the current working directory. Note you still need to explicitly request the desired behavior upon extraction, the adjusted command for compression is not enough. See the next paragraph to learn why this is a good thing.

Advantages over the general way:

- The archive to be created (e.g. `archive.tar`) can be specified as a path relative to the true working directory.
- You can specify some paths (to files to be archived) as relative, other paths as absolute. The question is about all absolute paths, but in general you may want to mix them.

Additional notes:

- `zip` acts as an archiver and as a compressor. This is not very Unix-like (see ["do one thing and do it well"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy#Do_One_Thing_and_Do_It_Well)). If you want to compress with `tar`, compress the resulting archive or [tell `tar` to compress](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_68.html#SEC134) on the fly during creation.
- In the example you used `-r` to enable recursion. With `tar` this is the [default behavior](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_53.html#SEC117).
- In the example you used `-x` to exclude some file(s). With `tar` it would be like `--exclude=/folderB/noisefile.\*` or `--exclude='noisefile.*'` (this one would also exclude one file in `folderBB`). Read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_section/tar_48.html#SEC110).

Example:

```
# archiving
tar -cPzf archive.tgz --exclude='noisefile.*' /*.txt /folderA/*.txt /folderB
```

```
# extracting
tar -xPf archive.tgz
```

---

#### Why not extract absolute paths by default?

Default behavior of extracting every path relatively to the current working directory is a good thing. This way, even if you're root, you don't need to worry if some archive (that you expect to just extract files in the current working directory) turns out to be rogue and extracts files elsewhere (e.g. it could overwrite `/etc/passwd` or whatever). You can allow this potentially dangerous behavior by *deliberately and explicitly* opting for it (with prior `cd /` or with a non-default option like `tar -P`).

---

#### What if I *really* want to use absolute paths by default?

This alias

```
alias tar='tar -P'   # but think twice
```

will inject the relevant option to every `tar` invocation in an interactive shell. Alternatively a wrapper function or a wrapper script can be used to inject the option. The wrapper script will easily work even if invoked from another script (for comparison: normally aliases don't work in scripts).

The general way can also be implemented as a script for a given archiver, although the most basic approach (that only changes the directory to `/` before invoking the real archiver) will result in relative paths being interpreted with respect to `/`, regardless of the current working directory. This can be fixed with proper command line parsing and inside logic; not a trivial task in general though.

Anyway **I do not recommend changing the default behavior.** The previous paragraph explains why. If I were you I would accept the need for non-default actions upon extraction; I would perform them *advertently* whenever needed.

---

#### Hints

The general way places you in the root directory. You will probably want to `cd` back to your true working directory. Useful tricks:

- `cd -` is equivalent to `cd "$OLDPWD" && pwd`. This is a basic way to `cd` back.
- `pushd /` instead of `cd /`, `popd` at the end. I know it's faster to type `cd /` and `cd -`, but if you are/get used to `pushd`+`popd` in your everyday work then you will probably use them in this case naturally, without a second thought, without breaking your routine.
- A subshell, e.g. `(cd / && unzip …)`. This will not change the current working directory in the main shell. The trick is particularly useful thanks to the fact variables are expanded before the whole subshell executes; this means you can use `$PWD` to pass your true working directory:

  ```
    (cd / && unzip "$PWD"/archive.zip)
  ```